# Any way to do this using LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have one foreach loop, i want to do it using LINQ

```
foreach (int i in indexes)
{
    char[] ch = new char[1];
    input.CopyTo(i, ch, 0, 1);
    chars.Add(ch[0]);
}
```

- **indexes** is a list of integers
- **chars** is a list of chars
- **input** is a string

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's see what your code does.

```
char[] ch = new char[1];
input.CopyTo(i, ch, 0, 1);
```

This is the documentation of `CopyTo`:

> Copies a specified number of characters from a specified position in this instance to a specified position in an array of Unicode characters.

So you're always copying a single character of the string to a character buffer of length one. For this case specifically, there is a much easier way to do that - and it doesn't even involve a temporary character buffer:

```
char ch = input[i];
```

Now your next line becomes much simpler:

```
chars.Add(ch);
```

So, in total you have this:

```
var ch = input[i];
chars.Add(ch);
```

This variable is used only once and it can obviously be inlined where it's used:

```
chars.Add(input[i]);
```

And so the whole loop becomes:

```
foreach (var i in indexes)
{
    chars.Add(input[i]);
}
```

This is a special case of a `foreach` loop, in which each iteration calculates "something" (`input[i]`) and at the end it adds that "something" to a collection (`chars.Add`). Fortunately, this is also a very typical case of a loop that can be easily turned into LINQ.

First, you need to identify the *source*, which is usually the object you did the `foreach` on:

```
indexes
```

Then, you need to identify the *selector*, which is the code that calculates the "something" you were adding, and pass that code to a `Select` method:

```
.Select(i => input[i])
```

At this point, you have this:

```
indexes.Select(i => input[i]);
```

And you can add it to the list as it is:

```
chars.AddRange(indexes.Select(i => input[i]));
```

But if you have the special case where the list is empty (for example, because you've just created it), then you may now be looking at something like this:

```
var chars = new List<char>();
chars.AddRange(indexes.Select(i => input[i]));
```

This is also a very common case and there's the `ToList()` extension method that can simplify it even further. That method basically enumerates the query and creates the list for you, saving you the trouble of calling the constructor and the `Add` or `AddRange` methods:

```
var chars = indexes.Select(i => input[i]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
chars =
   indexes
   .Select(index => input[index])
   .ToList();
```

This will throw if one of the indexes is out of range, but so would your original code. Also, you may need to concat if you need to preserve what was already in `chars`.